# Vite / Vue / Vuetify: Many not explainable network requests

Tags: vue.js, npm, frontend, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm working on my first little Vue Project (Simple CRUD Application). I am using Vite, Vue3 and Vuetify. PNPM as Package Manager.

Development went smooth till now and I never encountered some bigger issues. It always bothered me that the page was a little slow, but I never really investigated it deeper. Suddenly I realized that there are many many request calls in the backend (500+ calls, all to my localhost, See Screenshot for more details). The Frontend itself should only do 2-3 requests to my python backend.

[image: many requests]

Unfortunately, I do not know at which stage of development this started, so I don't have any clue where I should look for the problem. Most requests are initiated from some .ts/tsx files and are requesting mostly .mjs or .sass files.

I guess the problem is probably some wrong configuration anywhere at the top level of the Frontend application. I encountered the problems on all pages my frontend offers. Tested on multiple machines and different browser, always the same problem. The Application itself works as expected, just a bit slow.

In the console I only see the following output, nothing to worry about, right?
[image: warns in console]

I know my question is a bit generalized and its probably not that easy to help. Could you probably help me where to focus my search on? Which files/configs could be interesting to share/investigate deeper? I googled and did not find anyone with a similar problem.

Thank you

Comment: That's how Vite works, don't worry.

Comment: vite is serving all the files necessary to run your app.  vuetify is a fairly large library.  as you can see from the file names, many of them are vuetify related.  when you build for production all these files will be bundled together.  it's not anything you need to worry about in a dev environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing your app in development build so don't worry about it. The way Vite bundles your app in development and production is very different.

#### In development

Vite takes advantage of native ES modules in the browser to speed up your dev server. It starts the server first, then based on the server needs, it will transpile your code (if needed) and serve through HTTP request. That said, if you are using 500 components in a route, you will see 500 HTTP requests corresponding to these components.

#### In production

Vite chooses the traditional way like other build tools. That is bundling all your apps into a single file (actually it is more than a single file but the idea is that). The reason is well-documented in the [Vite document](https://vitejs.dev/guide/why.html#why-bundle-for-production):

> Even though native ESM is now widely supported, shipping unbundled ESM in production is still inefficient (even with HTTP/2) due to the additional network round trips caused by nested imports

**Conclusion,** if you really care about your page speed, you need to make a production build and test on it

Comment: So fetching hundreds of files are intended. Do you use vite in development? Have you found anyway to reduce number of files it's fetching on dev mode ?

Comment: I do. Why do you need to reduce the number of files on dev mode?

Comment: It takes really long time to load on refresh or initial load.

Comment: If you are developing with a 3G connection it might take time. But with normal network conditions, it works just fine. For me, it's nearly instant. Regarding your question, I don't think there is a way to reduce the number of files in dev mode